# Submitting form stores JSON data but never goes to php script:

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a html form that uses angular for validation etc, I have the data storing in a JSON object and would like to post it to my php mailer script, however not having the best of success, when submitting the form it states a 200 status message and stores the JSON data however never goes to the php script:

html code snippet:
    
    
    First Name (required)
    
    First name is required.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.lastName.$invalid && !contactForm.lastName.$pristine }">
<label for="lastName">Last Name <span style="color:red;">(required)</span></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" ng-model="user.lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
<span ng-show="contactForm.lastName.$invalid && !contactForm.lastName.$pristine" class="help-block">Last name is required.</span>
```

Submit my details

js:

```
var validationApp=angular.module('validationApp',[]);
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, $window){        
$scope.submitForm=function(isValid){
    if(isValid){ 
      var grabUserData = {};
        grabUserData = JSON.stringify($scope.user);
        var currentUrl = window.location.href;
        var trimedlocation = currentUrl.substring(0, currentUrl.length-17);

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: trimedlocation + 'test.php',
                data : $.param({'data' : grabUserData }),
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.userData = response.data;
                console.log("OK", response);
            }, function (response) {
               console.log(response.data, response.status); 
            });        
        }
    }
});
```

php:

```
@$firstName = $request->firstName;
@$lastName = $request->lastName

echo "Form submitted \n\n********************************";
echo "Name: " +$firstName + " " + $lastName + "\n";
?>
```

I am very new to angular, but obviously need a bit of help :-) can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that all you need to do is change the `$http` to use `params` instead of `data`. If you do that, you should be able to pass `$scope.user` directly to `params`.

In order to test my theory, I wrote the simple example below.

---

I wrote a completed endpoint similar to the one you posted. I ran the endpoint from a local PHP server by typing `php -S localhost:8000 -t ./` at the command line.

**PHP**

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-    Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

header("HTTP/ 201 Created", true, 201);

$firstName = array_values($_REQUEST)[0];
$lastName = array_values($_REQUEST)[1];

echo "Name: $firstName $lastName";
```

I didn't modify your HTML.

**HTML**

```
<form id="contactForm" data-ng-submit="page.submitForm()">
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactForm.lastName.$invalid && !contactForm.lastName.$pristine }">
<label for="lastName">Last Name <span style="color:red;">(required)</span></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" ng-model="user.lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
<span ng-show="contactForm.lastName.$invalid && !contactForm.lastName.$pristine" class="help-block">Last name is required.</span>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Hover, I made a few changes to the Javascript. I used my own server URL and then changed the request to use `params` instead of `data`. I passed the `$scope.user` data variable directly to the `params` attribute.

**JS**

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', [])
validationApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http) {

        self.submitForm = function() {

          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:8000/test.php",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            params : $scope.user
          }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.userData = response.data;
            console.log("OK", response);
          }, function (response) {
            console.log(response.data, response.status);
          });

        };
    });
```

I entered `Foo` and `Bar` in to the first name and last name fields respectively. This resulted in the following response from the server.

```
{
  data: "Name: Foo Bar", 
  status: 201, 
  config: {…}, 
  statusText: "Created", 
  headers: ƒ
}
```

Comment: I tried out using those amendments, but the form still doesn't go anywhere. I am using my localhost running on a mac osx server.

I am clearly missing something, but I have no idea what!

Comment: Are you able to post the error message that you're receiving?

Comment: That's the thing there are no errors.. In the console window;
Status: 200
StatusText: "OK"

Forgive me, but is there something specifically that I should be looking out for via the console window?

Comment: I see. To my knowledge your "print" response isn't going to return anything from PHP to Angular. Not unless it's returning an actual HTTP Response. I'll see if I can come up with a better Angular and PHP example.

I did notice that in your PHP above, that there is a missing semicolon after your `$request->lastName` variable.

Comment: I just create a very quick PHP, HTML, and Angular example, using the 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' content for the data. Try following along with the above example by changing your `data` to `params` and passing in your $scope.user directly (for troubleshooting purposes). If you have any questions, let me know.